# SQL Server Pivot Multiple Values

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Using SQL Server 2012.

I have the following table.  The Style and colour are passed as a parameter:

```
Style    Colour    Size  Whse         Stock   Sales   4WeekSales    ATP
ABC123    AS12      10   London         2       3         6          7
ABC123    AS12      12   London         4       6         8          10
ABC123    AS12      14   New York       6       8         9          12
ABC123    AS12      10   New York       7       5         7          5
```

But need the data to look like this with the sizes along the top:

```
Whse                10    12   14
Lon
  Stock             2     4     6
  Sales             3     6     8      
  4WeekSales        6     8     9
  ATP               7     10    12
New York
  Stock             7            6
  Sales             5            8
  4WeekSales        7            9
  ATP               5           12
```

Points to note - the size field needs to be dynamic - sometimes it can be  6 /8/10/12, sometimes it can be XS/S/M/L etc

Also their are more than two whse's - this is just an example.

I did make a start in T-SQL:

```
use SafetyStock
go

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(Size)
FROM (SELECT p.Size FROM dbo.vw_optimums AS p
GROUP BY p.Size) AS x;
SET @sql = N'
SELECT SKU, Style,' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
SELECT SKU, Style, p.Size, p.SAFETYSTOCK
FROM dbo.vw_optimums AS p
) AS j
PIVOT
(
SUM(SAFETYSTOCK) FOR Size IN ('
+ STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
+ ')
) AS p;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

However, this works but only pivots on the stock - how do I also pivot by Sales\4WeekSales\ATP and also groupb by the whse?

Thank you in advance.

This is my latest code. If I take the SEQNO out it works, but I need this so the sizes appear along the top correctly e.g. S / M / L / XL / XXL etc or 6/ 8 / 10 / 12

```
DECLARE @SizeColums VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Seq Integer
SELECT
@SizeColums = COALESCE(@SizeColums + ',','') + QUOTENAME([Size]),
@Seq = SEQNO
FROM    vw_optimums1 
GROUP BY [Size],[SEQNO]
ORDER BY [SEQNO]  


DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
SELECT  Whse,
    [Types],' +
    @SizeColums + '
FROM    (SELECT * FROM vw_optimums1) t
UNPIVOT ( 
 [Type]
FOR [Types] IN ([Stock],[LWSALES],[L4WSALES],[ATP]) ) up
PIVOT (
MAX([Type])
FOR [Size] IN (' + @SizeColums + ')
) p
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the closest I can get you is this.

```
DECLARE @SizeColums VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @SizeColums = COALESCE(@SizeColums + ',','') + QUOTENAME([Size])
FROM    vw_optimums 
GROUP BY [Size]

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    SELECT  Whse,
            [Types],' +
            @SizeColums + '
    FROM    (SELECT * FROM vw_optimums 
    ) t
    UNPIVOT ( 
         [Type]
        FOR [Types] IN ([Stock],[Sales],[4WeekSales],[ATP]) ) up
    PIVOT (
        MAX([Type])
        FOR [Size] IN (' + @SizeColums + ')
    ) p
'
```

This actually uses UNPIVOT first to get the breakdown by size, then pivots based on size.

You'll get a result like this based on the sample data.

```
Whse     Types          10          12          14
-------- -------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
London   4WeekSales     6           8           
London   ATP            7           10          
London   Sales          3           6           
London   Stock          2           4           
New York 4WeekSales     7                       9
New York ATP            5                       12
New York Sales          5                       8
New York Stock          7                       6
```

Comment: Thank you so much, data looking better.

Comment: I've tried this but on closer inspection the data is put on a new row for each  size for each whse.  I need the qty's all on one row for the whse.  Any ideas?

Comment: should give you one row per whse/types  if you dont want the types listed you just need to remove it from the select

Comment: @Michael Here is a sql fiddle of this example..  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48998/2

Comment: thank you but still not correct - its still creating a new row for each size

Comment: you're selecting something that's distinct between each size then..  pivot groups data on every field not pivoted, so if they're not the same they won't line up.. post the actual data and it would be easy to fix

Comment: Do I just post the data here?  Sorry - I'm a total newbie

Comment: you can just update the SQL Fiddle data if you want..  after you insert the values, click build schema

Comment: you the man!  I had a sequence to sort the sizes in.  When I remove this it now works!  I will need to sort by the size though so they appear in the correct order along the top - S \ M L etc or they can be 8 \ 10 \ 12 \ 14